# Beers sold in the US with little or no carbonation

Tags: carbonation

What types of beer have lower or no carbonation?

Comment: Why limit to local?   We don't even know your local.   Just open pour in glass and leave in fridge.  Brewing produces CO2 so not going to get no.

Comment: There's a good chance this question will get closed by admin if it isn't rephrased. The US is large.... Paparazzi is right, we don't know where you are. Why do you want low carbonation beers? Why do they have to be local? There are styles of beer that have naturally lower carbonation, if you expand the scope of your question and ask in general "What types of beer have lower or no carbonation and why?" you'll for sure get good answers. Then you can see which local breweries make those styles. Just trying to help, hope you find what you're looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

What you will be looking for is a ***Cask ale or cask-conditioned beer*** these are all generally very low carbonation or non at all due to only being left in a cask

> "Beer brewed from traditional ingredients, matured by secondary
>   fermentation in the container from which it is dispensed, and served
>   without the use of extraneous carbon dioxide"

If you go to an ale bar they will usually have at least one cask ale on I have not done a tour of America, so I cannot for sure tell you of places in America for low carbonated beer, but as for the what type of beer Cask Conditioned is definitely what you should be looking for.